# Save byte to file

Tags: c++, file

I am saving one byte in cycle to file. 
If I save in first (binary) a7 and then b5, in hexdump I can found b5a7. Is it right?

Added code:

```
char byte = 0; // this can change
ofs.write((char*)byte,1);
```

Comment: Well, why don't you just try it out?

Comment: Why? It may be the case if you save/load them as a word but not as bytes.

Answer (score 4):

No, not normally. If you write one byte at a time, they should be in the order you wrote them. The byte-swapping will occur on a little-endian machine if you write a two-byte quantity:

```
short x = 0xa7b5;

fwrite(&x, 2, 1, some_file);
```

Now (assuming a little-endian machine) the file will contain 0xb5 followed by 0xa7.